# 2014 Cruze lt won’t start. New battery, New starter?

Tags: battery, starter, jump-start

Went to jump start car after sitting over night lights and wipers came on. Heard 5 clicks and engine wouldn’t start. After 45-60 seconds with jump car shuts off completely. After replacing the starter attempted jumping Cruze again. This time no clicking wipers and lights came on turn key car completely shuts off. Any ideas what could be the problem? The battery was replaced less than a month ago.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have a bad connection either at the battery or where the battery cables connect at the other end. What you are describing usually happens when the connection is not great and will disconnect after a bit. If you can jossel the connection and it causes the power to be good, then it is exhibiting a short. Pull the connections and clean them on both ends to ensure there's good connection. Once done, you may find it will work after jump starting or charging the battery.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked battery voltage? It should be at least 12.2 volts. If not, you've got something draining the battery. Even with a jump on a completely dead battery, you still may not be able to start the engine. The dead battery is sucking all the juice from the jump